# Battleship puzzle with no clues

Tags: logical-deduction, strategy, grid-deduction

Suppose I have a standard [Battleship Puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(puzzle)), but with no clues (no square uncovered) at the start. Then I'm given 5 "fires" that uncover a square, what would be the best strategy to chose a square to uncover?

[image: Puzzle example]

Edit:

In the first picture I have the board, the second one is the starting position which unique solution is the board from pic1 and the final picture is my initial state, from which I, ideally, want to obtain a state which unique solution produces the board from pic1

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: I suspect that the answer here will only really be findable by brute-force computer search, so I'm not sure this is really a good puzzle. (Also, do you see the results after each fire or do you pick all five separately? Do you see just "hit" or "miss", or the specific shape of that cell? How do you measure "best"?)

Comment: Isn't this essentially asking what the best strategy is for the two-player game of [Battleship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game))?

Comment: @Deusovi each fire returns complete information about the square: miss or the ship part hit. And yes, it really is for computer to find, but evaluating all possible solutions and then firing to find the correct one takes too long, so I wondered if there's any strategy to filter out solutions at the start.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis but here we have the numbers of ship parts in each row and column, while in standard Battleship there is no information at all

Comment: Then how do we answer the question? It will depend on the outside numbers. Some grids are fully solvable no matter which five cells you choose, because they're solvable without any internal clues at all.

Comment: @Deusovi I mean, one answer could be: enumerate all possible solutions and filter out as much as possible with fires, no? I was just looking for a better one, if there is any

Comment: What's the metric? Highest chance of hitting any ship? Minimizing the length of smallest ship hit (the smallest are hardest to find) ? What's the opponent model, random placement, adversarial placement?

Comment: The image includes the number of cells occupied per row and columns, which changes the problem massively. @Sepfins, please clarify whether we should use those

Comment: @Jeffrey, yes, those should be used, it's the point of the [battleship puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(puzzle))

Comment: Is the intended result here just getting a single hit?

Comment: @IanMacDonald this is the real thing to clarify: do we want to maximize the number of hits or the probably of at least a hit, or ...

Comment: @Jeffrey as a best case scenario I would like to use these 5 fires to reduce problem to one with a unique solution, but realistically I'd try to, at least, uncover the squares that any solution will have as many same squares as the real hidden solution.

Comment: Can the battleship puzzle here have multiple solutions? Because usually normal puzzle only has one unique solution so no need to fire AT ALL because you know for sure where are the ships by logic alone.

Comment: I edited the question in hope that it will explain the problem better visually

Answer (score 1):

So, here's what I might do:

> I would probably start where the largest numbers intersect as I would probably have the best chance to hit something there.  For example, the 5 and 4.
>  If so, the rules state I would then know the shape of what was underneath. Thus, knowing the direction the ship was facing (if an end piece) or if the ship was larger than one cell (middle section).
>  As I progressed, I would follow the direction of the hit ship and try to stay away from any 0,0 or low-number intersections since I only have 5 attempts and they would be wasted.

Answer (score -4):

The best strategy is to

> try top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right.

I play with my son and he *always* try to hide a ship there.

Comment: unappreciated humour :-)